# perl batch rename files in command line

Tags: perl

I want to rename files with 'sr' in their names, replacing 'sr' with 'SR'. This one succeeded：

```
ls | perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;if(/(.*)sr(.*)/){rename $_,$1."SR".$2}}'
```

But this one failed:

```
ls | perl -e "while(<>){chomp;if(/sr/){rename $_,$\`.'SR'.($')}}"
```

with this error message:

```
Not enough arguments for rename at -e line 1, near "rename ,"`
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

It seems that $_ has become an empty string, but I don't quite understand why. Thanks for any explanations.

Now quotes have been an interesting problem and this is my test:

```
ls | perl -e "while(<>){chomp;if(/sr/){print $_;print\"\n\";print $\`,$&,($');print \"\n\";print $_,$\`,$&,($');print\"\n\";print $_;print\"\n\"}}"
```

outputs this:

```
3sr
3sr
3sr
3sr
sr1
sr1
sr1
sr1
sr2
sr2
sr2
sr2
```

it seems that when using alone, $_ is not empty; but it become empty when using along with $`,$& and $'. According to the last line of each file, I guess $_ has temporarily changed when not using alone?

Besides, according to a1111exe's answer, I test this:

```
ls | perl -e "while(<>){chomp;if(/sr/){print \$_,$\`,$&,($');print \"\n\"}}"
```

and got this:

```
3sr3sr
sr1sr1
sr2sr2
```

Comment: Is this not just because you've used " around the perl code and thus anything beginning with a $ will be treated as a shell variable rather than a perl one?

Comment: but this one work as expected:
`ls | perl -e "while(<>){chomp;if(/sr/){print $_}}"`
It will print file names

Comment: besides, I changed the use of quotes because otherwise $' variable will raise problems. I tried $\' and $\\' but of no use.

Comment: @mkHun question edited.

Comment: @a1111exe question edited.

Comment: @jsjie when it is becoming empty.? It is not becoming empty. We need to escape the `$` symbol like `print \$_,$\`,$&,($');`. And I'll check why here we need to escape.

Comment: @mkHun but we don't need to escape it in `print $_;` so I think this variable must have changed temporarily

Answer (score 2):

First in linux we should use single quote instead of double quote.

And instead of ls command you can use perl inbuilt function glob

And to capture the pre and post match you can use the $POSTMATCH and $PREMATCH from English module

so your one liner should be

```
perl -MEnglish -e 'while(<*>){chomp;if(/sr/){rename $_,$PREMATCH."SR".$POSTMATCH}}'
```

---

**EDITED**

Single quote and double quote is not about Perl this is about shell.

[Single quote](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)

> > Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

[Double quote](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)

> > Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’.

In shell script we are accessing the shell variable prefix with `$`, so while using `$` inside the double quote it is looking for the shell variable not a Perl variable. For example you can run the following line in your terminal,

```
m=4; perl -e "print $m;"
```

Here

```
m=4; perl -e "print $m;"
^                   ^ 
|                   Accessing shell variable
Assigning shell variable
```

Output is `4`. Because `m` is shell variable you are accessing the shell variable inside your Perl script.

And in windows, we need to use double-quote instead of single quote

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. But double quote will do if I use only "print" in my script. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that double quotes mess between your shell environment and Perl. You can certainly do what @mkHun suggested. One other way:

`ls | perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;($new=$_)=~s/sr/SR/g;rename $_,$new}'`

Also, if you escape the '$' sigil in '$_', your oneliner will work too:

```
ls | perl -e "while(<>){chomp;if(/sr/){rename \$_,$\`.'SR'.$'}}"
```

I still don't get why though.. But it really seems like bash/perl interpolation issue.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize 'if' is not needed until I read your comment. Thanks.